# How to fill form fields according to drop down

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have a form with user name, address and email.
the list of names is coming from a database, what i need to do is that when i pick the user name, the address and email info fills the other 2 fields (i have another fields, but i only need those filled)
I'm using php with mysql database

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Nothing because every example i saw prepopulates a second drop down, and i don't need that

Comment: Use jQuery and ajax. Set a change event on the drop down that gets the info from a php script and populates the fields ... That should get you started ... once you write the code, if you still have issues, come back and let us know ... we'll be glad to help ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, you will have to modify this to match your element ID's and such, but this works for me.

Here is your HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function grabInfo(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("contentDiv").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
       document.getElementById("contentDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getinfo.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

<select name="users" onchange="grabInfo(this.value)">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select a person:</option>
    <option value="1">Person A</option>
    <option value="2">Person B</option>
    </select>

    <div id="contentDiv">

    </div>
```

And backend PHP (getinfo.php):

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];

//MySQL connection string


$sql="SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE <parameter> = '".$q."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo '<input type="text" id="address" value="' . $row['address'] . '">';
  echo '<input type="text" id="email" value="' . $row['email'] . '">';
  }
?>
```

`contentDiv` will be where the two text boxes are displayed. `getinfo.php` will be the PHP where the actual manipulation of the database will occur.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be optimal - actually I'm not positive it works since I'm not testing this at all, but I'm sure you will figure it out if it doesn't work:

Assuming your form has a name="personInfo", the name drop down has name="personName", and the address is a text input field named "address".

In the personName select tag add

```
onChange="updateValues()"
```

Then you will need some javascript that will be something like this:

```
function updateValue() {
var addresses = new Array();
<?php
//add some php code to populate the java array. Something like
for ($i=0; $i<$numAddresses; $i++) {
    echo 'addresses['.$i.'] ='.$addressFromDB[$i].';';
}
?>
document.personInfo.address.value = addresses[document.personInfo.personName.selectedIndex];   

}
```

and repeat the same kind of thing for the email